# Relational database mysql

Tags: mysql

I had a problem about joining two tables. The tables are spelling_answer_key which contains answer keys for spelling and its corresponding question, and the other is user_spell_answers which stores all the users answers. Now i want to join this two tables but can't able to get it right.

The first table user_spell_answers look like this

```
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| userid | int(11)     | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| qid    | int(11)     | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| ans    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The second table spelling_answer_key look like this

```
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| spell_ans_keyid | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| spell_qid       | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| answer_key      | varchar(1) | NO   |     |         |                |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now I want to select qid, ans, and userid from user_spell_answers and from spelling_answer_key I want to select spell_qid, and answer_key, based on the correct answer that the user answers on a specified question.

Please Help

Comment: Where are the correct answers stored?

Comment: on user_spell_answers table